# Javascript: Regexp search and extract strings inside "{ }"

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the string I want to search in.

```
Make {The Most|One of the most} Out Of Your {Real Estate|Realty|Property} {Purchase|Acquisition} When You {Follow|Comply With|Adhere To} { something } These Tips
```

It should search for and return parts of strings that are enclosed in curly braces `{ }` and must contain one or more pipe `|` symbol inside them.

Following is the regexp I came up with but it doesn't work.

```
/^{?([^{]*\|)*}$
```

Expected Output

```
[{The Most|One of the most}, {Real Estate|Realty|Property}, {Real Estate|Realty|Property}, {Purchase|Acquisition}, {Follow|Comply With|Adhere To}]
```

Note that `{ something }` shouldn't be a part of the output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `\{[^{}|]+\|[^{}]*}` https://regex101.com/r/kfToJ3/1

Comment: `{ something }` shouldn't be a part of the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use 2 negated character classes, making sure to match at least 1 times a pipe.

You could change the quantifier to `+` if there should be at least a single char (note that this could also be a single space)

```
{[^{}|]*\|[^{}]*}
```

*Explanation*

- `{` Match `{`
- `[^{}|\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except `{` `}`, `|` or newline
- `\|` Match `|`
- `[^{}\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except `{` or `}` or newline (which allows also another `|`)
- `}` Match `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UB4q3o/1)

```js
const regex = /{[^{}|\n]*\|[^{}\n]*}/g;
const str = `Make {The Most|One of the most} Out Of Your {Real Estate|Realty|Property} {Purchase|Acquisition} When You {Follow|Comply With|Adhere To} { something } These Tips`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

---

If there has to be a non whitespace char other that `|` `{` and `}` before and after the pipe:

```
{[^\S\n]*[^\s{}|][^{}|]*\|[^\S\n]*[^\s{}|][^{}]*}
```

*Explanation*

- `{` Match opening `{`
- `[^\S\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars except a newline
- `[^\s{}|]` Match a non whitespace char other than `{` `}` or `|`
- `[^{}|]*` Match 0+ times any char other than `{` `}` or `|`
- `\|` Match `|`
- `[^\S\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars except a newline
- `[^\s{}|]` Match a non whitespace char other than `{` `}` or `|`
- `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times any char other than `{` `}` or `|`
- `}` Match closing `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OyOEFj/1)

Comment: The regex still fails for string fragments like this one ... `{x|}` ... due to `*`. Changing it to `+` will fix this issue. But this one should already be sufficient enough ... [`/\{[^|}]+\|[^}]+\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/5HoWGF/1).

Comment: @PeterSeliger Yes, but that depends on what the OP would allow to match. Your suggested pattern would also match `{ | }`

Comment: If there should be at least a non whitespace char before and after the pipe `{[^\S\n]*[^\s{}|][^{}|]*\|[^\S\n]*[^\s{}|][^{}]*}` https://regex101.com/r/OyOEFj/1

Comment: Yep, that's correct twice. The last regex then gets my thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use positive lookahead to match the pipe `|` like this:

```js
const str = `Make {The Most|One of the most} Out {klm} Of Your {Real Estate|Realty|Property} {Purchase|Acquisition} When {|} You {Follow|Comply With|Adhere To} { something } These Tips
`;

const result = str.match(/{[^{}]*(?=\|)[^}]*}+/g);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This regex fails for instance with `{xy|ab} Out Of {klm} Your {xy|ab|klm}` at the `{klm}` fragment.

Comment: @PeterSeliger the OP said that the match should contain one or more pipes

Comment: The regex is too greedy and "eats" / matches this chunk ... [`{klm} Your {xy|ab|klm}`](https://regex101.com/r/5OjX4f/1) ... entirely.

Comment: works like a charm now, except of not really being in need of a positive lookahead if one just adds the pipe to the first negating character class ... so, instead of `/{[^{}]*(?=\|)[^}]*}+/g`, just `/{[^{}|]*\|[^}]*}+/g`.